# remote debugging axis2 service on tomcat with eclipse fails

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, apache-axis, remote-debugging

I'm following this nice tutorial on remote debugging with eclipse

http://wso2.org/library/225

I work with eclipse/tomcat/axis2 and I'm trying to remotely debug an application
that is hosted on localhost.
I've set env-vars CATALINA_OPTS to

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

and verified that port number is 8000.
I do not have a firewall (as far as I know..)

eclipse tells me that it failed to connect.
I checked netstat -a and I don't see anything that listens on
port 8000., even after I started tomcat. (maybe that is the problem?)
though the service is listed under when I go to
http://localhost:**8080**/axis2/services/listServices

when I tried to change the port to 8080 in eclipse,
I got a timeout (but not immediate refusal)

What can it be?